# Closure actions in Ember

Tags: ember.js, closures, action

I'm rewriting some old Ember code to use closure actions, but I'm new to Ember and I can't seem to figure out how to change a sendAction that hasn't got parameters.

This is the code in the component row.js:

```
 click: function() {
        this.sendAction();
      }
```

The row.hbs as well as the parent templates are just

```
{{yield}}
```

so I can't add anything there it seems. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: can you provide an example of something that calls the row component?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just `{{yield}}` all the way up is it possible that the click didn't actually do anything?

Usually the calling template would have something like `{{row action="doSomething"}}` [Ember Docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/#toc_sending-a-primary-action)

It's also possible there was some behavior here that kept sending the action up when you have a `{{yield}}` in which case you would want to just keep going up the tree until you found (somewhere) an `action="doSomething"` declaration. That is where you will start sending the action back down.

e.g.

```
{{top action="doSomething"}}
  {{row}}
{{/top}}
```

Would become

```
{{top}}
  {{row doSomething=(action "doSomething")}}
{{/top}}
```

Then `row.js`

```
click() {
  this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I finally found an action, way up. Thank you!